# Two subgroups whose orders are greater than square root of the group order have no trivial intersection

Tags: finite-groups

Two subgroups whose orders are greater than square root of the group order have no trivial intersection

I cannot come up with a critical idea.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Recall that if $H$ and $K$ are finite subgroups of $G$, then

$$o(HK)=\frac{o(H)o(K)}{o(H\cap K)}$$

I am using $o(L)$ to denote the order of $L$.

You also know $HK$ may itself not be a subgroup, but certainly every element of $HK$ is an element of $G$.

Comment: I got it. Then o(H∩K) is strictly bigger than 1. Thank you so much

Comment: @user233454 glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use $|H_1H_2| \cdot |H_1 \cap H_2| = |H_1||H_2]$ for $H_1,H_2$ subgroups of a group $G$.